# Can someone please help me . I need to move the paragraph to the left by few points. i have tried adding \hspace{} but not working

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

```
\newcommand{\MySectionNoPic}[7]{% input: years, logo, title, university, city, specialization, description
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{2cm}
\begin{center}
\hspace{-45 pt}{\small \bfseries #1} \\
\vspace*{0.1cm}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\hspace{-2 pt}\vline \hfill
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{8.3cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{\normalsize \bfseries #2}
\hfill {\footnotesize\faMapMarker  ~ #3}
\hspace{-45 pt}{\small \bfseries #3} \\
\hspace{-45 pt}\small {\emph{#4}} \\
\hspace{-45 pt}\footnotesize {#5} 
\hspace{-45 pt}\footnotesize {#6}
\hspace{-45 pt}\footnotesize {#7}
\end{minipage}}
```

}[image]

Comment: You should be able to move the entire minipage as a unit, depending on where it starts.  Try putting an `\fbox` around it to see the edges.

Comment: BTW, using the [t] option of minipage make the valign unnecessary.